# sec_to_time() breaking query with nested select

Tags: mysql

If I do a

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(100);
```

I get a correct timestamp, however if I do the following it breaks

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SELECT SUM(totaltime) FROM tablename WHERE entry_id = 2)
```

total time is stored as an integer value and the query 
returns a syntax error, can you do a nested select statement within a sec_to_time function?

This is being executed from a c# data adapter so I can't manipulate the data outside the query otherwise I would get the sum and do some maths on in.

Comment: try providing an alias for the returned column?  (try adding `as stuff` to the very end of your statement and change `sum(totaltime)` to `sum(totaltime) as tt`)

Comment: Maybe totaltime is varchar.Post more code or the schema.

Comment: Yeah might need to cast the total time to a number type.

Comment: @BradSeman it is already an integer in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra set of parentheses when calling a function on a subquery:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( (SELECT SUM(totaltime) FROM tablename WHERE entry_id = 2) );
```

in my test db:

```
mysql> select * from tablename;
+----------+-----------+
| entry_id | totaltime |
+----------+-----------+
|        2 |       100 |
|        2 |       200 |
+----------+-----------+

mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((SELECT SUM(totaltime) FROM tablename WHERE entry_id = 2));
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME((SELECT SUM(totaltime) FROM tablename WHERE entry_id = 2)) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 00:05:00                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I figured it out shortly after I posted and got it working but never got round to posting the answer so I've accepted yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(stt) as stt_stt
FROM  ( SELECT SUM(totaltime) as stt 
        FROM   tablename    
        WHERE  entry_id = 2) as x
```

but in the sql fiddle, that gives me `January, 01 1970 00:12:47+0000` and I'm pretty sure that's not what you want...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/819fd/2/0

(no guarantees on that but it's what I would start with)

Comment: nice try but SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(timetaken) as sum_tt

Comment: what kind of column is total time? can you run just `SELECT SUM(totaltime) as sum_tt FROM   tablename WHERE entry_id = 2` by itself and tell me what happens?  (and in your real code, there's not another column in that select, right?  so no `group by` issue...?)

Comment: totaltime is an integer and the sum query works fine outside of the sec_to_time

Answer (score 0):

This is the only other way I can think of.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(totaltime)) FROM tablename WHERE entry_id = 2
```